# Solving the differential equation $y' - \frac{1}{x} y = x^2\sqrt{y} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Which technique should I use for solving the follwoing DE?

$$
y' - \frac{1}{x} y = x^2\sqrt{y}
$$
 I have tried some algebraic manipulations but I could not recognize any pattern.

Comment: We tend to avoid titles consist of only latex code due to some browser rendering difficulties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

1. Divide by $\sqrt{y}$.
2. Think of the chain rule and make a substitution...

Answer (score 1):

First, $z=y/x$ yields $z'=x\sqrt{y}=x^{3/2}\sqrt{z}$. 
Then $u=\sqrt{z}$ yields $u'=\frac12x^{3/2}$ hence $u=\frac15x^{5/2}+c$. Finally, $y=xz=xu^2$ hence
$$
y=x\left(\frac15x^{5/2}+c\right)^2.
$$